# Symfony Request Not Available in EventSubscriber

Tags: symfony

Changes to my Entities are logged using an EventSubscriber for Doctrine lifecycle events. I want to log a request id alognside the entity change log entries to see what's happened in one single user action.

Adding the request id is as easy as this:

```
class RequestIdSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [KernelEvents::REQUEST => 'addRequestId'];
    }

    public function addRequestId(GetResponseEvent $event): void
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $request->attributes->set('RequestId', Uuid::uuid1()->toString());
    }
}
```

The problem is that the request does not seem to be available in the Doctrine EventSubscribers in a reliable way:

```
class EntityEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    public function __construct(DelayedEventDispatcher $dispatcher, RequestStack $requestStack, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->dispatcher = $dispatcher;
        $this->inventory = new EntityInventory();
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            Events::postUpdate,
        ];
    }

    public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args): void
    {
        // works
        $this->logger->debug($this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->get('RequestId')); 

        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $changes = $this->inventory->getChangeSet($entity);
        $event = new EntityUpdatedEvent($entity, $changes);

        $this->triggerAuditLogEvent($event);
    }

    public function triggerAuditLogEvent(EntityEvent $event): void
    {
        // request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Error: "Call to a member function get() on null"
        $event->setRequestId($this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->get('RequestId')); 
        $this->dispatcher->dispatch(FhrEvents::GENERIC_ENTITY_EVENT, $event);
    }
}
```

So what really bothers me is that the request seems to be available in one method and if I call the next one, it's already gone.

Comment: I don't know exactly know what's the problem here, but if the request is not available in the triggerAuditLogEvent(), you can simply pass the 'requestId' to 'triggerAuditLogEvent' that you can get inside 'postUpdate()'

Comment: This would result in a lot of code duplication as I listen to all Doctrine events.